Calling paste with another key when someone is on your webpage
I want to make it so that a user clicking "rightArrow" performs a paste of the most recent text in clipboard
  document.onkeydown = (KeyboardEvent) => {
    if( KeyboardEvent.key == "ArrowRight"){
        //call default paste?
    }
  }

Doing this in react and trying to do it without triggering a refresh of the entire element defined by a useCallback like appending the text in clipboard to the text in the div does.
Basically: is there programmatic way to call the browsers paste with a different key
I have tried adding the text to the innerHTML, but it doesn't update without element refresh.
I Also have tried using dependency passed to useCallback, but that triggers reload ofc.

Are you just looking for this?

@David, not exactly, I'm not trying to to get the value from the clipboard into a variable, but to instead use arrowright to call the browsers paste function, not create my own
